# Is $\oplus_{i \in I} M_i$ necessarily projective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If $\{M_i\}$ is a collection of projective modules over a ring $R$, then must the direct sum $\oplus_{i \in I} M_i$ necessarily be projective?

I understand that each direct sum of two modules is projective if and only if each direct summand is projective, for starters...

Comment: Yes, for a proof see Algebra (Hungerford, 2003) chapter IV section projective and injective modules, proposition 3.5.

Comment: You may want to use that a module is projective iff it is a direct summand of a free module.

Answer (score 1):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

Yes. You can either follow your nose with diagrams and the universal property of the direct sum, or else you can use the suggestion in the comments and look upon projective modules as summands of free modules (whence it is easy to construct a large free module with a summand that is the direct sum of your projective modules.)

On a related note, it is *not* true that an arbitrary product of projective modules is projective.  Dually, a product of injective modules is always injective, but an arbitrary direct sum of injective modules is not necessarily injective.